# Static IP addresses for OVM manager

Tags: ip, oraclevm

Anybody know about why we need static IP addresses for Computer that Oracle VM manager has installed ?
I mean, what exactly different between dynamic IP and static IP here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OracleVM Agents need to contact the OracleVM Manager, they do this using an IP address. If that IP changes without you wanting it to change (ie it dynamicallychanges) then the cluster breaks.